# How to have a polymorphic model's partials associate to different things on the same page

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Essentially, I have a binary voting system Like/Dislike. Thee class is called `Like` It has polymorphic associations to **likeable**:

```
class Like < ActiveRecord::Base
     belongs_to :likeable, polymorphic: true
end
```

and we have the class `Comment`, which also has polymorphic associations to **commentable** and can be liked

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
     belongs_to :commentable, polymorphic: true
     has_many :likes, :as :likeable
end
```

We have the class `Section`, which can also be liked and commented on

```
class Section < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :likes, as: :likeable
    has_many :comments, as: commentable
end
```

However, on the page `section#show` I display the Section information, the section likes, and then the comments (from a `comments/comments` partial). Here is the `Section#show` view:

```
<h1><%= exercise.name %></h1>
<p><%= exercise.description %></p>
<%= render 'likes/like_button' %>
<%= render 'comments/comments' %>
<%= render 'comments/comment_form' %>
```

However, I want the ability to vote on each comment.

The following code is from the `_comments.html.erb` - What currently doesn't work is the rendering of the `_like_button.html.erb` because it doesn't apply to the comment at hand.

```
<% @comments.each do |comment| %>
    <%= comment.content %>
    <%= render 'likes/like_button' %>
<hr />
<% end %>
```

And here is the `_like_button.html.erb` partial

```
<% if @like.nil? %>
    <%# No record of Like in table %>
    <%= form_for [@likeable, Like.new] do |f| %>
    <%= f.submit "Like" %>
    <%= f.submit "Dislike" %>
    <% end %>
<% else %>
    <%# Marks current chosen option, if the opposite option is chosen, the record is updated to reflect the descion by the user %>
    <%= form_for [@likeable, @like] do |f| %>
        <% if @like.is_liked %>
            Currently Liked!
            <%= f.submit "Dislike" %>
        <% else %>
            <%= f.submit "Like" %>
            Currently Disliked!
        <% end %>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

So ultimately, I just want to know how to make it possible to vote on a comment from within the `Section#show` view
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<% @comments.each do |comment| %>
    <%= comment.content %>
    <%= render 'likes/like_button', :like => comment.like, :likeable => comment %>
<hr />
<% end %>

<% if like.nil? %>
    <%# No record of Like in table %>
    <%= form_for [likeable, Like.new] do |f| %>
    <%= f.submit "Like" %>
    <%= f.submit "Dislike" %>
    <% end %>
<% else %>
    <%# Marks current chosen option, if the opposite option is chosen, the record is updated to reflect the descion by the user %>
    <%= form_for [likeable, like] do |f| %>
        <% if like.is_liked %>
            Currently Liked!
            <%= f.submit "Dislike" %>
        <% else %>
            <%= f.submit "Like" %>
            Currently Disliked!
        <% end %>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```